# Will BigSur Beta update do a fresh install or upgrade Catalina?

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program, beta, big-sur

when you install the BigSur Beta, does it upgrade the current installation of Catalina (if there is one) or will it always to a fresh install?

Best

Comment: If you accept all the defaults during the install it will upgrade your Catalina to Big Sur.  If this comment doesn't help, you need to add more detail to your question.

Comment: when I installed BigSur on my testing SSD (which had a copy of Catalina from earlier in the year), the program just upgraded the OS, leaving all of my files and applications in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should always be an upgrade.